# How can I convert this JS const to TSX in a Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, three.js

I've have been going through the code in this really fascinating project https://github.com/MaximeHeckel/linear-vaporwave-react-three-fiber. It's a 3D next.js app that allows 3D rendering and animating of meshes and camera views in the browser. I would love to convert this code to `tsx` instead of the original `js`. How would I do that...?

This is an example of a random boilerplate page written in `tsx`:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          Get started by editing{' '}
          <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.tsx</code>
        </p>

        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>Documentation &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p>
          </a>

          <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>Learn &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Examples &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Deploy &rarr;</h2>
            <p>
              Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

This is the type of code that I'm used to working with in Next.js

This is a little snippet from `pages/index.js` in https://github.com/MaximeHeckel/linear-vaporwave-react-three-fiber

```
const Scene = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {!mounted ? null : (
        <Canvas
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            display: "block",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            zIndex: -1,
            outline: "none",
          }}
          dpr={Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2)}
          linear
          antialias
        >
          <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
            <color attach="background" args={["#000000"]} />
            <fog attach="fog" args={["#000000", 1, 2.5]} />
            <OrbitControls attach="orbitControls" />
            <PerspectiveCamera
              makeDefault
              position={[0, 0.06, 1.1]}
              fov={75}
              near={0.01}
              far={20}
            />
            <Light />
            <Landscape />
            <Effects />
          </React.Suspense>
        </Canvas>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Linear - React-Three-Fiber</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="A reversed-engineer versioned of the WebGL animation from the Linear 2021 release page. Recreated by @MaximeHeckel"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <div className="label-container">
          <p className="label">
            ⚡️ Originally inspired by the{" "}
            <a href="https://linear.app/releases/2021-06">
              2021 Linear release page
            </a>
          </p>
          <p className="label">
            ✨ Reverse-engineered and recreated by{" "}
            <a href="https://twitter.com/MaximeHeckel">@MaximeHeckel</a> with
            React-Three-Fiber
          </p>
          <p className="label">
             How I built this?{" "}
            <a href="https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/vaporwave-3d-scene-with-threejs/">
              Building a Vaporwave scene with Three.js
            </a>{" "}
            (Three.js only)
          </p>
        </div>
        <Scene />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I figure "Home" is easy to convert because I can just change `export default function Home() {` to `const Home: NextPage = () => {` and add an `export default Home` at the bottom of the page.

"Scene" looks more challenging to convert. First of all the return html is wrapped in `<> and </>` which is unfamiliar to me, and I keep seeing things like `React.useEffect` and `React.Suspense`. It seems weird to declare "React" first instead of just "useEffect."

Could someone please convert the "Scene" const to typescript code and from there I will be able to translate the rest of the file?

Answer (score 2):

'Const scene' should work in TS aswell, you can add FC and an interface though, if you want to be able to use props later!
The empty '<>' is just used to wrap your return. If you want to return multiple HTML like this

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

You will have to wrap them in a parent tag. Like this:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div> 
</div>
```

You could switch out the empty the empty '<>' to something else aswell, like a div!

For the 'React.useState' etc, you can just import them from react and use them directly!

```
import {useEffect, useState, FC, Suspense} from 'react'

interface Props {}

const Scene:FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {!mounted ? null : (
        <Canvas
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            display: "block",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            zIndex: -1,
            outline: "none",
          }}
          dpr={Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2)}
          linear
          antialias
        >
          <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <color attach="background" args={["#000000"]} />
            <fog attach="fog" args={["#000000", 1, 2.5]} />
            <OrbitControls attach="orbitControls" />
            <PerspectiveCamera
              makeDefault
              position={[0, 0.06, 1.1]}
              fov={75}
              near={0.01}
              far={20}
            />
            <Light />
            <Landscape />
            <Effects />
          </Suspense>
        </Canvas>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```